# how to get value from java script then store in php variable

Tags: php, javascript

> **Duplicate:**
>     [Access a JavaScript variable from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php)

hi

i want get value from java script, then i will use the value in php, both are in single php file.

send how to connect with these two in single file....

thanks

Comment: So why not use PHP to get the value directly?

Comment: hi
i want example code for connect these two in single file..
can u help me

Answer (score 0):

you can use post or get request to your current page (or to another page) using `<form>` tag or ajax.  Then in the php you will use [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) (or [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) or [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)) which act as associative array with the key being the name of your variable.  So if you submitted mypage.php?foo=bar

in php `$_REQUEST['foo']` will be bar.