# Outputting Javascript from PHP, but Javascript doesn't get executed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The PHP script doesn't seem to call `dis();` function..Here it is:

PHP:

```
if (!$_SESSION['user']) {
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>dis();</script>";
 }
```

JS:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function dis() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#main_text_area").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
    }
```

When I place just  `$("#main_text_area").attr("disabled", "disabled");` it disables correctly...but I need to do it on a function call...Thanks for comments.

Comment: "The PHP script doesn't seem to call dis(); function" --- sure, because PHP knows nothing about JS

Comment: PHP doesn't call javascript; your browser does. PHP simply outputs the data to be used by whatever client (in this case a browser) requested the data.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016701/creating-jquery-ajax-requests-to-a-php-function/7016795#7016795

Comment: You should check produced code. Check if "dis()" is declared before called. Some browsers also have built-in js debuggers. (Try pressing F12 and look into errors console).

Comment: Ok...I see..PHP is server-side based , JS client...but it is possible to call PHP from JS ( the other way round..)

Comment: @MrX "*call PHP from JS*" - That's AJAX

Comment: @Mr X: "but it is possible to call PHP from JS" --- no. It is possible to call JS from JS.

Comment: @Tomasz HA..It works ! Exactly as you suggested JS should've been declared before PHP function call...so it is possible. Thanks !

Comment: @MrX There's a very important distinction you're missing here. PHP isn't doing any interacting with javascript whatsoever. PHP is outputting javascript code that interacts with other javascript code.

Comment: Crazy idea but why not just use `<input id="main_text_area"<?php if (!$_SESSION['user']) : ?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif ?>>` or similar?

Comment: @Herbert ...Ajax or as Tomasz wrote - by declaring JS before PHP.

Comment: @Phil Could do this as well...true. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr X - you can't call PHP code from JS. If you use AJAX you are making a request to the webserver but your JS doesn't know or care whether that request is handled by PHP, ASP, JSP, or whatever. All it knows is that it gets some response back. At no point is your JS directly calling PHP code, and at no point does your PHP call JS code.

Comment: @nnnnnn: That's an important distinction. Well said.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend, instead of disabling the textarea, outputting the content of the `<textarea>` as static text.

Maybe something like this:

```
<?php if( !$_SESSION['user'] ): ?>
    <div class="text">
       <?php echo $textareaContents; ?>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <textarea id="main_text_area">
       <?php echo $textareaContents; ?>
    </textarea>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The Javascript approach you're currently taking is trivially easy to get around.

Comment: I would say that Javascript is trivially easy to get around ;-)

Comment: Exactly my point :)  Much better to handle the locking-down-the-element on the backend.