# Javascript Call function serverside

Tags: javascript, ajax, syntax, asp-classic

I need to call a Javascript function from the server side in Client side. I looked and didn't find any way how to do it. I looked also over AJAX but can't figure it out. I am using ASP ( clasic) not .net .

I need to call the function in client-side with a variable that comes from the client-side. Please help me!!! Thanks a million !!!

I am using a FlashMovies that is sending a value to a Javascript function through ExternalInterface class. The function in javascript receiving it is gAnswer(result) and in this function i would need to have something like :

Server side: 
function saveResult(result)
{code to be saved on the server goes here }

Client side :
function gAnswer (result)
{ saveResult(result) }    <- THis is the part i dont know how to do.
The function gAnswer is being called when the flash movie finished by itself. 
Would you be able to provide some code on how to ? thanks to each one of you who helped me =)

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016701/creating-jquery-ajax-requests-to-a-php-function/7016795#7016795

Comment: Do u have JQuery in your website? And where will your javascript execute, in the flash-movie or in a normal script code block <script></script> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call serverside function from client side via Ajax using this here:

```
function CallServersideFunction() {


        url = "CmsAjax.asp";
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            http = new XMLHttpRequest()
        }
        // code for IE
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        }

        if (http) {
            http.open("GET", url, true)
            http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponsearticleID;
        }
        isWorking = true;
        http.send(null);


}

function handleHttpResponsearticleID() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        if (http.responseText.indexOf('invalid') == -1) {
            var xmlDocument = http.responseXML;
            fno = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('id').length;
            if (fno > 0) {
            alert('Successfully done.')
                }
        }
    }
}
```

On this page "CmsAjax.asp" you can do your serverside operations.

Comment: Can you Please give me more info how it works what does it send into the  cmsajax how do i catch it . Sorry i am really new to it

Comment: Hi Dusty, you need to put content of CallServersideFunction() inside your savedata() function and then you need to make a .asp page where you need to do your database side operation. and handleHttpResponsearticleID() gives only reply from this .asp page if you new you can avoid this function for now.

Answer (score 0):

See http://beaconpush.com, http://pubnub.com, http://pusher.com, et al.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a function on the server from the client.

1. The client makes an HTTP request
2. The server constructs a response (HTML for this example)
3. The server delivers the response to the client
4. The client parses the HTML and executes any JS

By stage 4, the program generating the page will have terminated.

If you want something to happen on the server based on a client side script executing, then you need to make a new HTTP request. There are lots of ways you can do this:

- Click a link (and include the data in the URI)
- Submit a form
- Set the `src` or an iframe
- Use XMLHttpRequest (the most common form of Ajax)
- Create an `<img>` and include the data in the `src`
- etc