# How to send variable to php from javascript and return the result back to JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this code.

```
var book = document.getElementById('txtBook').value;
switch(book.toUpperCase())
    {
        case "GEN": var bk = "101"; break;
        case "EXO": var bk = "101"; break;
        case "LEV": var bk = "101"; break;
        case "DEU": var bk = "102"; break;
        ... and so on...
    }
```

I want to replace my `switch` with a database query. Since I learn from searching here that I can't do it straight from JS, I need to pass it to php Variable.

I want to know how to pass my `var book` to a php page like for example getbook.php

I will then make a query on php side. I want that result back to my JS for further processing.

I prefer method with no page refresh required.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at some of the pages at the right-hand side...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating jQuery AJAX requests to a PHP function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016701/creating-jquery-ajax-requests-to-a-php-function)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

```
$.get('getbook.php', {book: $('#txtBook').val()}, function(data) {
  // here you get your data and deal it 
});
```

Comment: Please don't answer to duplicate questions, leave a comment and a close-vote instead. Thank you!

Comment: @hakre Believe me. I have spent hours searching here and I can't find anything that will apply to my question. I have a feeling that my question will be down voted and worst closed. and frankly, I am really starting to avoid asking questions already. if this site has logs of user searches and if moderators can access that, you can go and ask moderators if I did search or not

Comment: @CharlesWayne: Well, then you probably have something in your mind that is not part of the written question you posted here. As all answers so far show (so not only me), you're looking for AJAX. Or you're looking for the other way round, passing a PHP variable to javascript, but that's also in the related section on the right. Don't search, browse each question on the right and read all questions and answers there. That should do it!

Comment: @hakre, that is what i have been doing for at least 3 hours now. I can't find so I ask. don't worry. I probably might not ask anymore. at least not here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is applying ajax.

Serve script(getbook.php):

```
$bookId = $_POST['book'];
//do some search stuff
$rows = getBookInfo($bookId);
$result = array('searchResult' => $rows);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Client script(remeber to include js for jquery):

```
postData = {book: bookId};
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/getbook.php',
     data: postData,
     dataType: 'JSON',
     success: function (jsonObj) {
        //use jsonObj.serachResult as array
     }
   });
```