# send form to php file using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i want to learn ajax by sending a form to a php file, for example for this form what should i do?
i need send this form (for example) to a php file (like send.php), using ajax and js.

```
<form name='myform' method='post'>
<input name='name' type='text'/></br>
<input name='email' type='text'/></br>
<input name='title' type='text'/></br>
<textarea name='message'></textarea></br>
<input name='send' type='submit' value='send'/>
</form>
```

Comment: This question has been asked 100 times already. Please look for answers before posting new questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating jQuery AJAX requests to a PHP function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016701/creating-jquery-ajax-requests-to-a-php-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple...

Change your HTML to this...

```
<form id="myform" name='myform' method='post' action="">
   <input name='name' type='text'/></br>
   <input name='email' type='text'/></br>
   <input name='title' type='text'/></br>
   <textarea name='message'></textarea></br>
   <button id="submitbutton">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Include Jquery library at top of page...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then add this script on the page...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#submitbutton').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   form = $("#myform").serialize();

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "yourpage.php",
     data: form,
     success: function(data){
         alert('Successful!'); 
     }});

   return false;  //stop the actual form post !important!
  });

});
</script>
```

THe processing on the other side is PHP....and Im not gonna show you that part....cuz I assume you already know how to process forms on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by using jQuery.

```
$("form[name=myform]").ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "send.php",
  data: { $("form[name=myform]").serialize(); }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Where msg will be the output from the send.php file.