# How do I send a form through ajax to my php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add a comments section. I have an ajax call that inserts a message to my database. I have php on the page to display all the messages from the table. When I click on the comment section nothing happens.

I tried to initially hard code some variable in javascript just to see if my ajax is atleast making an attempt to insert into my database and it did but then I found this answer 
[send form to php file using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553999/send-form-to-php-file-using-ajax)
and I  tried this but it does not work for me.

I made sure the click ID was achnaged and that the hp file was changed to macth the correct url but when I click on submit nothing happens.

I initially had this before I found an answer that I think should work but it does not. Here: [send form to php file using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553999/send-form-to-php-file-using-ajax)

```
var message='hey how are you';
var task=37;
var Domain='fun';
var Task_Number=37;


function messfunction() {
     $.ajax({  
            url:'mess.php',  
            type:'POST',  
            data:{task:task,Domain:Domain,message:message}, 
            success:function(data){  
               window.location.reload(true)
                  }
      });
}
```

This is what I have now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#Butt').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   form = $("#myform").serialize();

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "mess.php",
     data: form,
     success: function(data){ 
      window.location.reload(true)
     }});

   return false;  
  });

});
```

My Form I am using php to output the form, that is why you see php variables as the values.

```
<form   id= "myform" name ="myform"  method= "POST" action="">
  <input type= "hidden" name="User" value="'.$email.'">
  <input type  ="hidden" name ="date" value="'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'">
  <input type="hidden" name="task" value="'.$Tasknumber_modal.'">
  <input type="hidden" name="Domain" value="'.$domain_modal.'">
  <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  <button  id="Butt" >Comment</button>
  </form>';
```

Here is my mess.php page.

```
                    require('server.php');

                     session_start();

                        $User=$_SESSION['email'];
                        $message=$_POST['message'];
                        $domain1=$_POST['Domain'];
                        $task=$_POST['task'];


        $sqli= "Insert into Universe.Message (Message,Users,TaskNumber,urlDomain) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt =mysqli_prepare($link,$sqli);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ssis",$message,$User,$task,$domain );
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.serialize()` is more for `GET` requests in my opinion, as it basically transforms the form data into a string layout (`?q=Search+Query&id=12`).

Your first example seems to indicate that your PHP is decoding the formData, so try this instead with your second example:

```
var form = new formData($('form')[0])
```

Comment: I added your code and when I clicked on comment nothing happened. My php is using $_POST['name']  to get the data after the form is submitted. What do you mean by decoding form data?   Is that some kind of php function?

Comment: You have no input with the name “name”. Try substituting it with “User” or “date”, since you have those input names defined

Comment: I added my php that is usign the data above. When I click on comment seems as thought no attempt is made to run my php.