# Using a Javascript variable inside a php block

Tags: php, javascript, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (including escaping newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines)
>   [Access a JavaScript variable from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php)

I have a Javascript function that takes in one variable. The function has some php code inside it.  I want to use this variable inside the php section of the function. I couldn't get it to work. How is it done?

Comment: No-can-do, boss, at least not the way I think you're thinking :-) The PHP is being interpreted on the server before it's sent to the client. You can use PHP to populate a javascript variable directly, but going the other direction requires some kind of AJAX post.

Comment: this type of question is all over the web, please google it first

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php#answers-header

Comment: you want JS inside php or php inside JS ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your PHP code is being rendered on the server before being served to the client. I would recommend either converting the PHP code into Javascript code or creating an AJAX call to the PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

Start reading about AJAX! You will likely need to rewrite some of the code you have written but what you are attempting to accomplish is not really possible otherwise.

Comment: How easy is it to do with AJAX?

Comment: It is simple once you get used to it, you will definitely need to do some reading and learning but it is fairly simplistic once you have done it a few times.

Answer (score 0):

try with it

```
<script>
    var whatever = "<?php echo $phpVar ?>";
</script>
```