# sending javascript variable value to php within the same page

Tags: php, javascript

I just want to know if sending value of a javascript to php is possible.
here is the simple code of what i am trying to say.

```
<script language="javascript" >
var id = "data"
</script>

<?php
$getthevalueofid = var id;
?>
```

thanks!

Comment: Your PHP code on that page is long finished executing by the time the JavaScript runs client-side.

Comment: thank you for answering. do you have any suggestion as to how i am going to solve it? I have this javascript variable value, and i really need to use it on my PHP code.

Comment: Hi, Jonas. Check out this previous post to see if it answers your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789283/how-to-get-javascript-variable-value-in-php

Comment: @jonas, Solve what?  You haven't posted your actual problem... just your attempt at fixing it.  You're asking the wrong questions.  You didn't even tell us what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

Not the way your code sample is structured, no.  PHP is a server-side language and Javascript is a client-side language.  PHP is out of scope by the time any client-side script executes.

If you need to pass an object from the browser to your server you can use XMLHttpRequest (commonly referred to as AJAX).

Comment: thank you for answering. do you have any suggestion as to how i am going to solve it? I have this javascript variable value, and i really need to use it on my PHP code. Thanks!

Comment: @JonasFabriag - If you need the browser to pass data to your server, you have two options: having the user submit a `<form>` or use AJAX.  There are a plethora of examples of how to do this on StackOverflow.  Here is one that might get you started:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example

Comment: thank you! I'll try to study that one.

Answer (score 2):

To send a Javascript variable back to PHP, you need to do an AJAX request:

```
<script language="javascript" >
xmlhttp.open("GET","getvalue.php?id="+id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

And in getvalue.php you'd have:

```
<?php
$getthevalueofid = $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No way to do this. Use Ajax to pass javascript variable to php