# How to set cookies from remote JSON data?

Tags: php, json, cookies

I've got a url that returns JSON style location data for a user. I'd like to set this data into cookies but I don't know how. I'm a very inexperienced user who's just learning and would really appreciate some help with this. Here is an example of the url:

http://beta.geocoding.cloudmade.com/v3/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/api/geo.location.search.2?format=json&source=OSM&enc=UTF-8&limit=10&q=48.77615073;9.16416465

Thanks so much!

Comment: This link should be helpful: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: @barjey: I think that OP doesn't need JS solution. [And don't forward users to w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What have you tried so far? Show us some code please.

Comment: @Glavić, didn't know that about w3schools, thanks for the info.

Comment: @barjey, I think I need go with php on this one since it interacts better with my cms.

Comment: @user1251007 Actually, the only code I have is in javascript. I've been banging my head on that for a day and then it dawned on me that even if i got that to work, for me to get the data into my cmd (expressionengine) i'd need to use php anyway. I do know how to set cookies in php but parsing a json response into cookies is a concept I don't grasp enough to even sketch out some example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an untested idea ...

1. Read the json file from the URL as simple text string.

   ```
   $json_url = 'http://beta.geocoding.cloudmade.com/v3/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/api/geo.location.search.2?format=json&source=OSM&enc=UTF-8&limit=10&q=48.77615073;9.16416465';
   $text = file_get_contents($json_url);
   ```
2. Store as json and use base64, just in case:

   ```
   $value = base64_encode(json_encode($text));
   ```
3. Store the cookie:

   ```
   setcookie("test", $value);
   ```

Comment: That worked very well, the json data slips right into a cookie, just perfect! There is another aspect to this that I didn't realize would be a problem till now. I need to supply the lat/long of the user in the url of the json request. As far as I know that can only be obtained by javascript. Do you have any advice how to construct the url so I can include lat/long data from javascript? Or, is there way to get lat/long from php? I've looked everywhere for this and can't find any way to do this...

Comment: Just a quick search yielded [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789283/how-to-get-javascript-variable-value-in-php).    Please also consider upvoting my answer. ["If an answer has helped you solve your problem and you accept it you should also consider voting it up."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/181353)

Comment: I'd love to upvote you as you really helped me a lot but I can't do it because apparently I'm not allowed to up vote until I have a reputation over 15. I'm 1/2 way there! When I get there (assuming I do) I'll gladly come back here and do it!

Comment: BTW, the tip for passing the variables was great. I'm probably going to play with this all day to put it together. Thanks!