# Javascript Button/Switch - Values to another php page

Tags: javascript, php, button, switch-statement

first off all, i want to thank for this site, it helped me alot. 
So, I want to do a button/switch that when it is pressed it passes a value "1" to another page and when it's not pressed (default) it passes the value "0".
I already have a code that i made with the help of user of this site and youtube:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function onoffalarm(){
    var onof = document.getElementById('onof');
    var switchonoff = document.getElementById('switchonoff');
    if(onof.style.display=="block")
    {
        onof.style.display= "none";
        switchonoff.src= "images/buttonOFF.png";
        switchonoff.title= "Turn On";
        window.location.href="led.php?value=0";
    }else{
        onof.style.display="block";
        switchonoff.src= "images/buttonON2.png";
        switchonoff.title= "Turn OFF";
        window.location.href="led.php?value=1";
    }        
}
```

```
<img id="switchonoff" onmousedown= "onoffalarm()" src="images/ButtonOFF.png" width="217" height="217" alt="" title="Turn On">

<div id="onof">
</div>
```

With this code, the only value that passes to "led.php" is "1", but as i said, i want it to pass the value 1 when pressed and 0 when it is not pressed. 
Adicionaly, I also want to know how can i save the button state when i make a refresh for exemple. 
How do i do that.

**Seen Already**

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-3BxXdISG8
>
> [How to get JS variable to retain value after page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh)
>
> [How to get javascript variable value in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789283/how-to-get-javascript-variable-value-in-php)

Thanks for the help

Comment: @synquall maybe it very useful information, but im a noob, so i dont know who to use the code that you gave me. the code that i made (that doesnt work well xD) take me alot of time because im new at this.
And about the other problem that only sends 1 to the page led.php you can help with the solution. keep in mind that im very bad at this.
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies in JavaScript to store variables which are available browser-wide. These variables are not lost when you refresh the page or close the page. It will only be deleted if the user clears their cookies or the cookies expire.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

setCookie("state", 0, 30);
```

**setCookie(nameOfCookie, valueOfCookie, expiryInDays)**

And you can fetch them too.

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)  {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name)==0) 
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

var cookieState = getCookie("state");
```

**getCookie(nameOfCookie)**

Hope it helped.