# how to increment value in javascript with the value from the form

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<script>
    function remain()
    {
        var k=0;
        var rem=<?php echo $count; ?>;
        var cap=document.getElementById("cap").value;
        var k=k+cap;
        var diff=rem-cap;

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = diff;

    }
</script>
</html>

<html>
<form method="post" action="list.php" target="_blank">
    Enter the capacity:
    <input type="number" name="cap" id="cap"  min=1 max=36 onchange="remain()">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="get seating">
</form>
</html>
```

My question is: in the HTML form I will enter the capacity. When I entered the capacity it will be directed to javascript and remaining strength must be show by subtracting the capacity from the total count (ex: i entered the capacity as 36 and let the count be 100).

Now the cap 36 is less from 100 and remaining 64 will be shown. But when again I entered the cap 36 it should be less from remaining 64. But this was not happening.

Comment: After calculation of `diff` you may set value of `diff` to the input you got value from: `document.getElementById("cap").value = diff;`

Comment: As a side note, notice that after submitting your form, you might lose your calculation data unless you use some state persistence mechanism (cookies, server side session etc.)

Comment: Why are there two `html` tags for what appears to be one document? That is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?? Click the <kbd>geat seating</kbd> button after mentioning the capacity.

```js
var rem = 100

function remain() {
  var k = 0;
  var cap = document.getElementById("cap").value;
  var k = k + cap;
  rem = rem - cap;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = rem;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="list.php" target="_blank">
  Enter the capacity:
  <input type="number" name="cap" id="cap" min=1 max=36>
  <input onclick="remain()" type="submit" id="submit" value="get seating">
</form>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: @PavanKumar : What value do you expect ?

Comment: thank u thank u very much its works very nice. exactly what i want. thank u my friend

Comment: another question friend how can i send the value rem in javascript to a variable in php

Comment: @PavanKumar : Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789283/how-to-get-javascript-variable-value-in-php

Comment: its not working properly. my intention is when the rem=0 the form to enter the capacity must be disabled. please help me