# How to get javascript value into php variable without reloading the page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here I want to get a value from **JavaScript** to **PHP** variable without using any POST or GET method.

Here I'm giving HTML code:

```
<input type="number" name="days" id="days" class="col-sm-2 form-control" placeholder="DAYS"> 

<input type="number" name="night" id="night" class="col-sm-2 form-control" placeholder="NIGHT"> 
                            
<button id="generate" onclick="GetValue()" class="btn btn-danger">Generate</button>
```

Javascript Code

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#generate").on('click', function(){
        var days = $("#days").val();
        var night=$("#night").val();
        var base_url = $('#base').val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: base_url,
        data: {'days' : days, 'night': night}, 
        success: function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

php code

```
<?php
$days = $_POST['days']; 
$night = $_POST['night'];
echo $days . " " . $night;
?>
```

Variable value not working.

Comment: did you know ajax?

Comment: I didn't used before.

Comment: you can resolve this problem with ajax

Comment: please can you help me to overcome this problem....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JavaScript variable value in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789283/how-to-get-javascript-variable-value-in-php)

Comment: when I pass value through link its reloading the page and I lose all other field value. that's why I don't want to use GET method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly assign javascript variable to PHP variable, that's why ajax is used.

If you want to perform operations on client side variables to server-side without page refresh and using the same page then you have to write the PHP code on the top of the page before anything start of client-side and the use exit to break after the PHP response is completed. and in jquery ajax forget the URL part as you are using the same page for request and response.

*Note: Make sure to include jQuery*

Cover all the element in form tag so we can simply send data using serialize method.

<kbd>index.php</kbd>

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['days'])){
        $days = $_POST['days']; // you can write the variable name same as input in form element.
        $night = $_POST['night'];

        //Perform any operations on this variable and send in response whatever you want it will send the response to success function of jquery ajax and you can check response in `data`

        echo $days . " " . $night;
        exit();
    }
?>


<!--<form id='frmsbmt' method='post' action='#'>-->

    <input type="number" name="days" id="days" class="col-sm-2 form-control" placeholder="DAYS"> 

    <input type="number" name="night" id="night" class="col-sm-2 form-control" placeholder="NIGHT"> 

    <button id="generate"  class="btn btn-danger">Generate</button>
<!--</form>-->
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#generate").on('click', function(){
            var days = $("#days").val();
            var night=$("#night").val();
            var base_url = $("#base").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                //url: base_url,
                data: {'days' : days, 'night': night}, //$("#frmsbmt").serialize(), //form serialize will send all the data to the server side in json formate, so there is no need to send data seperately.
                success: function( data ) {
                    console.log(data);
                    //alert(data);
                    // It will write the response in developer tools console tab or you can alert it.
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Without using form is it possible ?

Comment: yes, it's possible @raheez please check the updated answer.

Comment: one more help I created a variable var base_url = $('#base').val(); for getting url so how can I put this on the url field in the ajax

Comment: I didn't get you can u please explain in more detail or update the question what you exactly want to ask?

Comment: if you are getting url from some hidden field or somewhere then you can do that thing as above i have updated my answer please check once

Comment: error occur when I run this code undefined days and night field

Comment: so you are getting an error after clicking on generate?

Comment: I open the source, script side  url shows the base_url variable name only. but I want to print the actual link.

Comment: what is your base_url?

Comment: your index page contains all the html code and php code right?

Comment: I am using codeigniter framework so both are inside in the code

Comment: that doesn't matter what framework you are using you can create a php separate page to get response but you still want to get response from the same page then there is last option i am updating my code wait

Comment: Nothing print in the screen

Comment: check updated answer and make sure you are sending value in days field

Comment: let me check please

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AJAX call for this.

```
function GetValue() {
    var str = document.getElementById('days').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'text.php',
        data: {
            someValue: str
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using in same page so in url what should I give ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question without using any post or get method to retrieve the variable is impossible. One language is a server side language, one language is a client side language, if the two languages never communicate through an established standard and protocol passing a variable between the two are impossible. PHP is translated server side which means the client side interface doesn't really know it exists unless there is an action that is tied to a method namely get or post. An Ajax request uses either POST or GET or one of the other established methods to communicate.