# How to display the below data in a php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

From the below code I need to pass the value of "data1" to php file using variable.

Js file:

```
document.getElementById('data1').innerHTML=e.point.name;
```

Html Code :

```
  <p id="data1"></p>
```

From the above js and html file how can I pass the value of "data1" to php..

Comment: use jQuery ajax

Comment: try to use jquery ajax, it should help you

Comment: Please give more context what about what you're trying to do as your description is a bit ambiguous

Comment: Html and php source codes are in same file or different file ?

Comment: we are using seperate file

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var data1 = $('#data1').text();

$.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {myvar : data1},
  success: function (data) {
     console.log(e)
  },
  error: function (e) {
     console.log(e)
    }
   });
});
```

Than in your php script access the variable like this

```
$my_variable = $_POST['myvar'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not send JavaScript variable value to PHP, you can send PHP to JavaScript,
If you want to send data you have to use url and pass. make it url and send.

USE this [Dublicate]

[How to get JavaScript variable value in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789283/how-to-get-javascript-variable-value-in-php)