# how to access javascript variables inside php script?

Tags: javascript, php

What should I do if I want to save a javascript variable value, say `var a`, inside a php script variable without using post/get method or ajax?

```
 <script>
  var count=3;
   $("#add_driver").click(function () { 
  $( "#add_driver_section").replaceWith( "<div class='wrap-input100 validate- 
 input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100' > <span class='label-input100'>Gender</span> 
 <div class='contact100-form-radio m-t-15'> <input class='input-radio100' 
  id='male-radio"+ count +"' type='radio' name='type-product"+ count +"' 
    value='male' checked='checked' > <label class='label-radio100' for='male- 
      radio"+ count +"'> Male </label></div><div class='contact100-form- 
      radio'> <input class='input-radio100' id='female-radio"+ count +"' 
      type='radio' name='type-product"+ count +"'  value='female' > <label 
      class='label-radio100' for='female-radio"+ count +"' > Female </label> 
       </div></div>");  
  count++;}
   );
</script>
```

i have edited my question to give you guys a little more perspective as to what i want to acheive. Here i first want to check if `type-product"+ count +` is set or not. if it is set then i want the radio button's `selected` attribute to have the value selected.

Comment: why don't you want to use post/get method or ajax?

Comment: i am ok with ajax but i dont want a very complicated or lengthy code.

Comment: are you able to use jquery?

Comment: @RyDog yes, as long as it is not too complicated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods . I just can't understand, why everything should be done in the hardest possible way instead of standard well-known tools ..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JavaScript variable value in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789283/how-to-get-javascript-variable-value-in-php)

Comment: What is the reason why you can't send that data using a conventional method?

Comment: @Teemu it would be a great help if you can tell me a what standard well-known tools i must use. pardon me for the complex code since i am a newbie and still learning

Comment: Ehh ... get, post, ajax. And you don't need server-side script to set a selected attribute, that can very well be done with JS too.

Comment: @Teemu please show me the ajax code for it.

Comment: Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) before going further.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var a = "variable a";
</script>

<?php

    $a = "<script>document.write(a)</script>";
    echo $a;
?>
```

try this code to save js variable in php variable

Answer (score 0):

`Cookies` can be used to share data between server and browser because these are accessible from sides. Data can be set to cookie using JAVASCRIPT ([Set and get Cookies in JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)) and can be accessed at server using `$_COOKIE` variable in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php variable in your javascript, but, dont put it on .js file instead you should put in on .php or .html file.

```
<script>
var a = '<?php echo myvariable ?>';
</script>
```

but if you want to dynamically store your variable for future use, you can use cookies to store the variable.

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
function eraseCookie(name) {   
    document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  
}
```

and you can use the code like this :

```
function createhtmlcode(){
    var a = getCookie('typeprod');

    var myhtml = '<p>html code here';
    if (a) {
        myhtml += <input type='radio' name='type-product"+ count +"'  value='female' selected >
    }else{
        myhtml += <input type='radio' name='type-product"+ count +"'  value='female'>
    }
    myhtml += 'your next code here</p>';
    return myhtml;
}
$(document).ready(function(){

    setCookie('typeprod',true,7); //7 day, use this to store your variable to memory/cookies.

    $("#add_driver").click(function () { 
        var htmlcode = createhtmlcode();
        $( "#add_driver_section").replaceWith(htmlcode);
    };
});
```