# how to pass a variable from a template {{data}} to php to be exploded

Tags: javascript, php

i need to explode this {{{data.comment}}} in php.
I'm a beginner thank you.

```
<span class="um-activity-comment-text">
<?php            
        $comm = '{{{data.comment}}}';
        echo explode(' ', $comm)[0]; //--> this is not working. 
        ?>
</span>
```

Comment: data.comment is json?

Comment: Where are script tags?

Comment: What template language? _How_ is it “not working”? Please go read [ask].

Comment: yes data.comment is json

Comment: then first you need to do `json_decode()`

Comment: [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is what you might need. However, {{{data.comment}}} doesn't seem to be proper JSON

Comment: how to do it sir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JavaScript variable value in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789283/how-to-get-javascript-variable-value-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

by putting `{{}} 'you already do' echo 'so try

`<?php   echo explode(' ', data.comment)[0];  ?>`

Comment: the result is datacomment