# Cannot get value of php variable in accordance with the value of js variable

Tags: php, javascript

I have this html file that tries to call `script2.php` when the button is clicked:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <a id="test" href="try.html" onclick="return false;">
            <input type="submit" id="gen" value="Generate!" onclick="dothis();"><br />
        </a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function dothis() {
                var url = document.getElementById("test").valueOf('href');
                alert(url);
                $("#quote p").load("script2.php");
            }
        </script>

        <div id="quote"><p></p></div>
    </div>
```

The `script2.php` has this in it, in which I try to get a `text file` from `try.html`:

```
<?php
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
  $file = 'test_put.txt';
  $url = "try.html";
  $current = file_get_contents($url);
  $current2 = strip_tags($current);
  file_put_contents($file, $current2);
  echo "Thanks for your response!";
?>
```

You see, the php file doesn't get the value of `$url` directly from the value of `var url` inside the javascript thing. While what I want is the `$url` value can vary in accordance with the `var url`.

I'd tried:

```
$url = "<script>document.write(url)</script>";
```

And this:

```
$url = "<script language ='javascript'>
          var url = document.getElementById('test').valueOf('href');
           document.write(url);
       </script>";
```

Then it twice said, `failed to open stream`.

I've googled and searched in SOF as well to address this problem, all I could find was the server-side and client-side thing that make this won't work simply. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php) too, but since I'm not doing such form I can't extract that solution into my problem.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
$("#quote p").load("script2.php?url=" + url);
```

That passes the URL in the query string.  Then retrieve it in "script2.php":

```
$url = $_GET["url"];
```

Comment: Oh thank you, you saved me. Hope you don't mind my asking, what does this mean? `?url=" + url`?

Comment: @Safira it's the query string - that passes data to the server, which PHP can retrieve using `$_GET[]`.