# How to pop up radio button for user input according to dropdown list option?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a dropdown list consists of addons items value. WHen the $a="Driver"; selected or submitted then a radio button should show up,asking users to select either one. One for 8th hour and the other for 16th hour. How to do this please?

the dropdown list as below:

```
<select name="addon">
                   <?php
                   mysql_select_db($database_bumi_conn, $bumi_conn);
                   $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_addons WHERE status=1";
                   $result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
                   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                   {
                       $a_id=$row['addOns_id'];
                       $a=$row['addOns'];

                   ?>

                   <option value="<?php echo $a_id;?>"><?php echo $a;?></option>
                   <?php

                   }
                   ?>

                   </select>
```

I tried something like this,

```
 <script>
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please type either 8 or 16 for 8th hour and 16th hour respectively", "Driver");

    if (person != null) {


        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";


    }
}
</script>
```

It pop up a box asking to type the abovementioned value. But how to store the value in a php variable?

MY HTML FORM

Pick up dateReturn dateAddon ItemsQuantity
                        
                       
                       
                        
                            
                            
                            months

```
                    $mm=array_map(function($val)
                     {
                        return sprintf('%02d', $val);
                      }, range(1, 12));
                    foreach($mm as $i)
                    {
                        $this_day = date('m'); 
                        $selected = ''; 
                        if (strlen($i) == 1) { 
                        $i = '0'.$i; 
                        if ($i == $this_day) $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
                        } else { 
                        if ($i == $this_day) $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
                        } 

                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $i;?></option>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <span class="">date</span><br/>
                <select name="date" class="">
                <?php
                    $mm=array_map(function($val)
                     {
                        return sprintf('%02d', $val);
                      }, range(1, 31));
                      foreach($mm as $i)
                      {
                        $this_day = date('d'); 
                        $selected = ''; 
                        if (strlen($i) == 1) { 
                        $i = '0'.$i; 
                        if ($i == $this_day) $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
                        } else { 
                        if ($i == $this_day) $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
                        } 
                          ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $i;?></option>
                          <?php
                      }
                ?>
                </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <span class="">year</span><br />
                 <select name="year" class="">
                <?php
                    foreach(range(2014,2050) as $year)
                    {
                        $this_day = date('Y'); 
                        $selected = ''; 
                        if (strlen($i) == 1) { 
                        $i = '0'.$i; 
                        if ($i == $this_day) $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
                        } else { 
                        if ($i == $this_day) $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
                        } 
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $year; ?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $year; ?></option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <span class="">months</span><br />
                 <select name="months_2" class="">
                    <?php



                    $mm=array_map(function($val)
                     {
                        return sprintf('%02d', $val);
                      }, range(1, 12));
                    foreach($mm as $i)
                    {
                        $this_day = date('m'); 
                        $selected = ''; 
                        if (strlen($i) == 1) { 
                        $i = '0'.$i; 
                        if ($i == $this_day) $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
                        } else { 
                        if ($i == $this_day) $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
                        } 

                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $i;?></option>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <span class="">date</span><br/>
                <select name="date_2" class="">
                <?php
                    $mm=array_map(function($val)
                     {
                        return sprintf('%02d', $val);
                      }, range(1, 31));
                      foreach($mm as $i)
                      {
                        $this_day = date('d'); 
                        $selected = ''; 
                        if (strlen($i) == 1) { 
                        $i = '0'.$i; 
                        if ($i == $this_day) $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
                        } else { 
                        if ($i == $this_day) $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
                        } 
                          ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $i;?></option>
                          <?php
                      }
                ?>
                </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <span class="">year</span><br />
                 <select name="year_2" class="">
                <?php
                    foreach(range(2014,2050) as $year)
                    {
                        $this_day = date('Y'); 
                        $selected = ''; 
                        if (strlen($i) == 1) { 
                        $i = '0'.$i; 
                        if ($i == $this_day) $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
                        } else { 
                        if ($i == $this_day) $selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
                        } 
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $year; ?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $year; ?></option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                   <select name="addon">
                   <?php
                   mysql_select_db($database_bumi_conn, $bumi_conn);
                   $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_addons WHERE status=1";
                   $result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
                   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                   {
                       $a_id=$row['addOns_id'];
                       $a=$row['addOns'];

                   ?>

                   <option value="<?php echo $a_id;?>"><?php echo $a;?></option>
                   <?php

                   }
                   ?>

                   </select>

                   </td>
                   <td>
                   <input type="text" name="qty" />
                   </td>
                   <td>
                   <input type="hidden" name="mm_insert" value="insert_log" />

                    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add"/>


                   </form>
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
```

EDITED:

```
<script>
       $('#radioButtons').hide(); 
       $('#addon').bind('click',function()
       {
           var optionSelected=$('option:selected',this);
           var valueSelected=this.value;
           if($valueSelected=='6')
               {
                   $('#radioButtons').show();
                   $("input[type='radio'][name='driver']").click(function()
                   {
                       var selected=$('input[type="radio"][name="driver"]:checked').val();
                       alert(selected);
                   });
               }else
                   {
                       $('#radioButtons').hide();
                   }
       });
   </script>
```

EDITED according to @punitha suggestion:

```
<td>
                           <br/>
                       <select name="addon" id='addon' id="addon" onchange="triggerAddon(this.value)">

                       <?php
                       mysql_select_db($database_bumi_conn, $bumi_conn);
                       $query="SELECT * FROM tbl_addons WHERE status=1";
                       $result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
                       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                       {
                           $a_id=$row['addOns_id'];
                           $a=$row['addOns'];

                       ?>

                       <option value="<?php echo $a_id;?>"><?php echo $a;?></option>
                       <?php

                       }
                       ?>

                       </select>

                       </td>
                       <td>

                         <br/>
                          <div id="ageConfirmation">
                           <input type="radio" id='ageeig'name="driver" value="8">8th Hour
                           <input type="radio" id='agesix' name="driver" value="16">16th Hour

                          </div>
                       </td>
//script

<script>

function triggerAddon(AddonValue){ if($.trim(AddonValue)=="Driver"){$('#ageConfirmation').show(); } }



function validateForm(){
if($.trim($('#addon').val())=="Driver"){
 if(!$('#ageeig').is(':checked') || !$('#agesix').is(':checked')) { alert("Please select either one"); }
}
}
        </script>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you had posted HTML example of your form, with some sample data. And your JS function doesn't really make any sense with what you are asking.

Comment: Concerning your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php

Comment: @CrazySabbath, I added my html form. I know the JS doesn't make good sense of what i really want. I just tried something where you can allow user to key in the input.I only need to show pop up box for value="Driver" in the dropdown list.That is to allow user to choose either 8th hour or 16th hour rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
something like this:
<select name="addon" id="addon" onchange="triggerAddon(this.value)">

In script:
function triggerAddon(AddonValue){ if($.trim(AddonValue)=="Driver"){$('#ageConfirmation').show(); } }

In html:
<div id="ageConfirmation">8<input type="radio" id="ageeig" name="age" value="8" /><input type="radio" name="age" value="16" id="agesix" /></div

while submit the form:
function validateForm(){
if($.trim($('#addon').val())=="Driver"){
 if(!$('#ageeig').is(':checked') || !$('#agesix').is(':checked')) { alert("Please select either one"); }
}
}
```

Edited

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<select name="addon" id='addon' id="addon" onchange="triggerAddon(this.value)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Driver">Driver</option>
    <option value="Security">HR</option>
    <option value="HR">HR</option>
    <option value="Assistant">Passenger</option>
</select>
    <br/>
    <div id="ageConfirmation" style="display:none;">
        <input type="radio" id='ageeig'name="driver" value="8">8th Hour
        <input type="radio" id='agesix' name="driver" value="16">16th Hour
    </div>

    <input type="button" onclick="validateForm()" value="Submit" />

<script>
function triggerAddon(AddonValue){
 if($.trim(AddonValue)=="Driver"){
    $('#ageConfirmation').show(); 
 } else {
    $('#ageConfirmation').hide(); 
 }
}

function validateForm(){
    if($.trim($('#addon').val())=="Driver"){
     if(!$('#ageeig').is(':checked') || !$('#agesix').is(':checked')) {
        alert("Please select either one"); 
        $('#ageeig').focus();
     }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: subramaniam, thanks for the comment. I will try and let you know.

Comment: subramaniam v, can we keep in touch as I'm very glad to come across an Indian female programmer!

Comment: @CrazySabbath I tried your way, it's just doesn't trigger anything. I posted my edited code ..Please have a look.

Comment: Is the comment for me?

Comment: you cannot do like this: <script>$('#radioButtons').hide();$('#addon').bind('click',function() add before starting jquery Like this <script>$('document').ready(function(){$('#radioButtons').hide()........

Comment: I tried your suggestion instead.Please look at the last edited part. I might missed somthing

Answer (score 0):

Check this (not pop radio buttons, but you should get the idea):

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6xv8s4zq/)

```
<select id="addon" name="addon">
    <option id="123" value="123">Driver</option>
    <option id="423" value="423">Option2</option>
    <option id="523" value="523">Option3</option>
</select>

<form action="" id="radioButtons">
    <input type="radio" name="hours_rate" value="8">8th hour rate
    <input type="radio" name="hours_rate" value="16">16th hour rate
</form>

$('#radioButtons').hide();
$('#addon').bind('click', function(){
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    if(valueSelected == '123'){

      $('#radioButtons').show();
        $("input[type='radio'][name='hours_rate']").click(function(){
      var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='hours_rate']:checked").val();
          alert(selected);
        });

    }else{
       $('#radioButtons').hide();
    }

});
```