# Storing information to database using JavaScript prompt function

Tags: javascript, php

If I were to do a JavaScript prompt and allow a user to enter the information, how do I store this information into the database?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['cancel_req_id']))
{

    echo "<script>var reason = prompt('Reason')</script>";
  $res = "<script>document.write(reason)</script>";

              $query="UPDATE booking SET status='Cancelled', s_approval='', s_authorize='', cancellation='$res' WHERE req_id='$id'";
              $result=$conn->query($query);

                    echo "<script>alert('Booking cancelled!')</script>";
                    echo "<script>window.location=('status.php')</script>";


}
?>
```

this is my current code.

Comment: mysqli! i search the net and they told me to use ajax! but i am not familiar with ajax!n so if anyone could help me with ajax i would appreciate much

Comment: then you should first search something by yourself, and only then ask here if you've some problem. what have you tried?

Comment: sorry! but yea i tried to do it with ajax but it doesnt work! hahas

Comment: **what** have you tried? post your code here

Comment: @Federico hi sir i have updated the code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php