# Can not convert a sessionStorage data to an array of objects in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get sessionStorage data to a php string variable. Then from there I am trying to convert it to a php array of objects. My target is to save stored data in sessionStorage to a mysql database. Following is the process I am following.

```
$jsonString = "<script>document.write(sessionStorage['sca'])</script>";
$arr = json_decode($jsonString );
var_dump($arr );      
print_r($arr);
```

The Output I am getting is NULL

What I want is the following

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass 
        Object ( [name] => iphone [s] => black [price] => 50000 [id] => 2 [qty] => 3 ) 
        [1] => stdClass 
        Object ( [name] => iphone [s] => black [price] => 50000 [id] => 2 [qty] => 3 ) 
      )
```

Can't figure what I am doing wrong

Comment: check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php

Comment: You are [decoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) a string, which, since it's not a json array, gives you null and probably also an exception. If you want to turn this string into a json element, try [encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it.

Comment: PHP pre-processes some code (php and html) and sends a page to the browser ... this is one way communication ... server -> client ... the two most common ways to send data from client to server is through a `<form>` submission or using AJAX