# How to access a javascript variable inside a php query?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to access a javascript variable inside a php query

```
function myFunction2(){
    Total=parseInt(point2)
    <?php
    $con->query("UPDATE eventlist SET P2 = $this.Total WHERE Eid=$PID");           
    ?>
  }
```

I want the query to set p2=value of total

I understand that php is a serverside script and I cant do this like this. What is an alternative to this.?

EDIT

ok i got this on the JS side

```
function myFunction2(){
       var Total = parseInt(point1)+parseInt(point2);
         $.ajax({ url: 'ajax.php',
         data: {'total' : Total},
         type: 'post',
         dataType:'json',
         success: function(output) {
                      alert(output);
                  },
          error: function(request, status, error){
            alert("Error");
  }
```

and if i put

```
echo $_POST['total']
```

in ajax.php i get an alert with the value passed. So i think the value is being passed properly.
But what i need to do is a Mysql Query.

```
$con->query("UPDATE eventlist SET P2 = $_POST['total']; WHERE Eid=1");
```

Something like this. How do i do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: You can do it via ajax.

Comment: you can do your update in new page, call it via ajax on this page.

Comment: I think you need AJAX, this is a good link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try send javascript value to another php page which contain your query

```
function myFunction () {
    var param = "value";
    $.post('query.php', { postvalue: param}, function(data) {
        //do what you want with returned data
        //postvalue should be the name of post parameter in your query page
    })
}
```

Comment: and in the php side how do i access the param?

Comment: $_POST['postvalue']

Comment: <?php   
   $con = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password",'events');   
    $con->query("UPDATE eventlist SET P2 = $_POST['Total']; WHERE Eid=1");           
        ?>

Why doesnt this work?

Comment: change "postvalue" in my code to "total" and remove ";" after $_POST['total']

Comment: just remove ";" after $_POST['total'] in last line

Comment: Did that.Still not updating the database.

Comment: Maybe you need some update $x = $_POST['total']; $con->query("UPDATE eventlist SET P2 = '$x' WHERE Eid=1");

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP in this way:

```
$total = $_POST['total'];
$con->query("UPDATE eventlist SET P2 = $total WHERE Eid=1");
```

Comment: i am using method 1. Please check the Edit in the question.