# How to pass JavaScript variable with php GET

Tags: javascript, php

I have online payment form. On-click I should pass following information to online payment company.

- Mid--->Merchant ID
- Amount--->Transaction amount (Integer: $50.25 = 5025)
- Currency--->Transaction currency code (ISO 4217)
- Description--->Transaction description (Can be used for item
  assignment)
- Reference--->Transaction reference (unique transaction value set by
  merchant)
- Language--->Language{az/en/ru)
- Signature--->MD5 hash of concatenated parameter length + value with
  secret key

Signature example:

```
$signature = Strtoupper(md5(strlen($mid).$mid.strlen($amount).$amount.strlen($currency).$currency.(!empty($description)? strlen($description).$description :"0").strlen($reference).$reference.strlen($language).$language.$key));
```

The resulting URL should be like this:

```
 https://test.millikart.az:7444/gateway/payment/register?mid=Test&amount=5025&currency=944&description=test1000&reference=T7D3EDB885A5BC3C&language=az&signature=9A9E510BE7094D94284F1AFFE00FA4DA
```

The amount of information that should be sent to an online payment company is a JavaScript variable that I get as a result of JavaScript calculations. I couldn't figure out how to achieve it. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access a JavaScript variable from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access a JavaScript variable from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php)

Answer (score 0):

### with ajax and FormData:

```js
$(document).ready( function(){

        
            let calculated = 3;
            
            let fd = new FormData();

            fd.append('calculated', calculated);
            
            
            $.ajax({
                url: "the_php_file_that_you_need_to_pass_it.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,

                complete: function (results) {
                    try {
                        let str = JSON.parse(results.responseText);
                         console.log(str)
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error(e.message);
                    }
                },
            });


        }) ;
```